# Getting AJAX response body for use in error callback

Tags: jquery, ajax

jQuery's AJAX error function has the following parameters:

```
error(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
```

What's the best cross-browser way to get the response body?

Does this work (reliably in all browsers)?

```
$.ajax({
  error: function(http) {
    alert(http.responseText);
  }
});
```

Comment: the http.responseText works on all the modern browsers, and the error handler is triggered for all 4xx and 5xx HTTP Status Errors.

You can vary the error handling by checking the HTTP status code accessible as 'http.status'

Comment: Keep in mind that you will not get the body if the response does not pass the CORS checks

Answer (score -4, accepted):

There is a hidden function that can extract the data from XHR istance:

```
var responseText = $.httpData(xhr)
```

If you pass `"json"` as a second parameter it will treat the response as a JSON string.

Note that you might get an error because there is no response (network problem for example). Make sure you cover that case as well. Also, I believe (not sure) that jQuery invokes the `error` handler if the server returns a `4xx` or `5xx` status.

Comment: Thanks. Judging from the source it looks like `xhr.responseText` will work for regular HTML data

Comment: It looks like the `$.httpData` function is gone as of jQuery 1.5.2 at least.

Comment: This response was outdated. There is no such method in jQuery API for now

Answer (score 98):

As of jQuery 1.4.1 you should use:

```
var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/.

Comment: After ensuring, of course, that the content type is actually JSON.

Comment: It now says, "As of jQuery 3.0, $.parseJSON is deprecated. To parse JSON strings use the native JSON.parse method instead."

Answer (score 31):

For a more recent and general answer (since jquery 1.5), I'd use the [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR) object:

```js
$.ajax(url).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(jqXHR.responseText);
})
```

Alternatively [`responseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#data-types) can be used to get the response body already parsed

```
$.ajax(url).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(jqXHR.responseJSON);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

One straightforward usage example with jQuery:

```
var url = '/';
$.get(url).then(
  function(response) {
      $("#result").html(response);
  },
  function(jqXHR) {
    $("#result").html('Error occurred: '+ jqXHR.statusText + ' ' + jqXHR.status);
  }
);
```

This should return the HTML of current website front page.

Then try entering a nonsense URL that doesn't exist and see the error thrown.
You should get "404 Not Found" from web server. Test it: JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7v8xmf09/1/)