# ajax get response error message

Tags: ajax, response, httpresponse, servlets

I'm using ajax inisde my jsp page. after getting to the servlet, I want to send back a respone with a message. 
at first I used "response.sendError(500 , "this is a test msg"); inside my servlet but when I tried getting the error message inside the ajax error function , I used xHR.responeText and got an html string that did contain the message , but it is not good for me , I want to get only the error message.
I also tried setStatus(500) , and contenttype - xml , but I still couldn't get the error message.

How can this be done? I want to send error code number 500 , but each time I want to send it with diffrent message , and then read it inisde the ajax callback function.

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming I understand your question right You want to recieve the error message as a plain string without html tags?

If this is the case you should write the text to the response and set the mime type (contentType to "text/plain).

So something like.

```
   PrintWriter writer = response.getOut();
   writer.print(errorMessage);
   response.setStatus(500);
   return
```

Make sure you haven't aready written to the response when you do this.

Comment: @Wes: this is what i did:                 response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=UTF8");                                 
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                out.print("test test test");
                response.setStatus(500); , but how do i get the message "test test test" from the ajax error function?

Comment: @Are you using a libray for Ajax?

Comment: @Wes: yes , i'm using jquery library

Comment: does this question help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084484/getting-ajax-response-body-for-use-in-error-callback?

Answer (score 1):

```
 error: function(error) {
                        targetNode.innerHTML = " text to display" + error;
 }
```

with jQuery

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url_,
        data: urlParams_,
        dataType: 'text',
        async: false,
        success: function(result_) {
            if (result_.length > 0 ){
                try{
                    result_ = $.parseJSON(result_);
                    result = result_;
                }catch (e){
                    alert(e);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your JS you need the read the xHR.status. Not the xHR.responeText. xHR.status should contain 500.

Comment: I know that , I asked about the message.