# Trying to display/parse a jQuery $.get/$.ajax HTTP 400 Bad Request response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm doing a simple jQuery `$.get` or `$.ajax` call to my API webserver (which has `CORS` enabled).

When I hit my endpoint `/orders/search` and fail to provide the correct/valid search filters, I return a nice `400 BAD REQUEST` but I *also* return some json error message in the BODY of the response:

```
{
    "Errors": {
        "Query": "An order id is required. eg. ABCD-1234"
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to retrieve this json payload when I use a jQuery ajax/get method to retrieve this information.

Here's the code I've got:

```
function doAjaxGet(endpoint, queryString, successFunction) {

    $.get(ApiWebsite + "/" + endpoint, queryString, function(data){
        if (successFunction != null) {
            successFunction(data);
        }
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, status, exception) {
        // This would be where I would actually parse the json payload 
        // for the failure reasons. This would usually be where the
        // validation failure messages would be displayed.
        $("#messageBox").text("error blah blah blah")
        .show()
        .delay(5000)
        .fadeOut();
    });
}
```

### Edit

It was suggested that my question is a [duplicate of this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23779461/30674). I checked that out and they suggest that to access the response payload I should do this:

```
$.ajax(url).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(jqXHR.responseText);
})
```

But the `responseText` property doesn't exist on my `jqXHR` instance.

Here's the picture of the `jqXHR` instance:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting AJAX response body for use in error callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084484/getting-ajax-response-body-for-use-in-error-callback)

Comment: Updated opening post. Duplicate suggestion doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Have you tried `jqXHR.responseJSON`? It's also in the dupe-link (answer with 60 upvotes)

Comment: @PeterB Updated OP to include image showing instance properties.

Comment: jQuery docs state that `jqXHR.responseText` or `jqXHR.responseXML` or `jqXHR.responseJSON` will be returned depending on the response type for the request. Is your server sending a content type header?