# 400 bad request in graphql

Tags: javascript, graphql

I am trying to insert a new product through a form with javascript  into database in grapqhl server and also that product should be displayed in zonaB with javascript ,but i am getting the error 400 bad request. Could someone tell me where is the mistake
here is html code

'''

```
       <form id="formular" action="#" method="POST">
          <label>Numar produs:</label>
          <input type="text" id="nr">   
          <label>Denumire produs:</label>
          <input type="text" id="nume" ><br>
          <label>Categorie produs: </label>
          <input type="text" id="categorie"> <br>
          <label>Descriere: </label>
          <input type="text" id="descriere"><br>
          <label>Imagine:</label>
          <input type="text" id="imagine"><br>
          <label> Pret:</label>
          <input type="text" id="pret"><br>
          <label> Disponibil:</label>
          <input type="text" id="stoc"><br>
          <button onmouseover="insereaza1()"> Insereaza</button>
     </form>
       <script>
     var $id = $('#nr').val()
     var $name = $('#nume').val()
      var $id_categorie = $('#categorie').val()
      var $descriere = $('#descriere').val()
      var $imagine = $('#imagine').val()
      var $pret = $('#pret').val()
      var $stoc = $('#stoc').val()


     function insereaza1() {
             creareProdus={"query":"mutation{createProduct($id:ID!, $name:String, $id_categorie:ID, 
             $descriere:String, $imagine:String, $pret:Float, $stoc:Boolean){createProduct(id:$id, 
             name:$name, category_id:$id_categorie, description:$descriere, picture:$imagine, 
             price:$pret,  available:$stoc){product{id }}}}"}

          setari={url:"http://localhost:3000",
              type:"POST",
              data:creareProdus,
              contentType:"application/json",
              success:vizualizareProdus}
              $.ajax(setari) 
           }
         function vizualizareProdus(){
           var x = document.getElementById("formular").method
          document.getElementById("zonaB").innerHTML = x
         }

       </script>
       </body>
      </html>
```

'''

Comment: A 400 status normally means there's something wrong with the query itself. It's either malformed or otherwise invalid. Please check the actual response from the server to determine the cause -- the response body will include an `errors` array with details about what went wrong. This can be viewed in your browser's dev tools.

Comment: OST http://localhost:3000/ 400 (Bad Request)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
insereaza1 @ proiectweb.html:109
onmouseover @ VM782 proiectweb.html:189 this is everything what it shows me

Comment: Open the network tab and examine the request there, not in the console. You could also get the response body [through jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084484/getting-ajax-response-body-for-use-in-error-callback)

Comment: the problem is because i have there an image that should be upload, but I don't know how to integrate code in my mutation . Can someone help me, please? I have in the form a label that has id = imagine(image) that should be stored in var $imagine, and after to be passed in the query : mutation

Comment: {"errors":[{"message":"POST body sent invalid JSON."}]} i am getting this error